# How long does user needs to wait when change password attempt exceed in AWS

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, passwords, amazon-cognito

I have implemented a change password feature using AWS Cognito but I face the limit of attempts. when user clicks forgot password more times it gives "Attempt limit exceeded, please try after some time". I need to know what is the exact time that it take to reattempt?

the error gives in console is like below,

```
{
code: "LimitExceededException", name: "LimitExceededException", message: "Attempt limit exceeded, please try after some time."}
code: "LimitExceededException"
name: "LimitExceededException"
message: "Attempt limit exceeded, please try after some time."
__proto__: Object
```

So any Idea about how log does user needs to wait when this comes?

Comment: Interesting! Couldn't see it listed on [Limits in Amazon Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html). Might be an anti-hacking limit to prevent password guessing?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes it's but the question is how long we need to wait.